# Pass custom tests to function

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, function

I have a function that takes incoming data, cleanses it, and runs an INSERT or UPDATE depending on the data.  What I need is the ability to pass custom data testing logic to the middle of the function each time I call it out. Thanks so much for the help from such a great website.

```
$tests = 'if($data[0] == '-') $data[0] = NULL';
$this->run_function($data, $table, $message, $tests);

public run_function($data, $table, $message, $tests){
if(isset($data['submit'])) unset($data['submit']);
//Other array manipulation here
echo $tests
//Pass custom testing on $data array here.
$this->db->update($data,$table);
// ETC.
}
```

Basically, I'd normally add a parameter to the function but that doesn't work when it's php logic you're try to pass.  Any ideas hwo to get around this?

Comment: Don't expect people to finish your work :) Post a concrete question with the minimum amout of code and then expect possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't know how to make the question generic.  I'll change the code to something more basic.

Comment: Why don't you just add the logic data where it should be instead of trying weird things?

Comment: The issue is, I need to rerun this function a few hundred times and each time I want to do slightly different testing on the data that gets passed to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up using was the php [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) function.  This way I was able to save the custom testing logic I wanted and pass it to my central function as a parameter.  Very helpful stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steve - but first, can you give an example?

You'll have to write the logic either way, so you may as well write the tests in the function, and use switch/case.

```
    function myTest($data, ... $test) {

        switch ($test) {
           case 'length':
               return ($data > 8) ? true : false;
               break;
           case 'foo':
               return ($data == 'foo') ? true : false;
               break;
           case 'bar':
               return ($data == 'bar') ? true : false;
               break;
           default:
        }
    }

$var = myTest('mydata', ..., 'foo'); // $var === false
```

or perhaps include more params:

```
function myTest ($data, ... $test, $param1 = null, $param2 = null, $param3 = null)...

$foo = myTest('mydata', ... 'length', 8);
```

(Unless you're testing against regular expressions, which you could pass as a string)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but I have a feeling there aren't isn't a better solution.  Thanks everybody.